# How to find text files with nothing but a pattern on a single line using bash

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to find text files using bash that contain nothing but a specific pattern on 1 line of the file.

For example, I have the following textfile:

```
1234123 123412341 0000 23423 23422
121231 123123 12312 12312 1231
567 567 43 234 12
0000
929 020 040 040 0000
```

This file contains a line (line 4), that exclusively has pattern `0000`. 
I tried `ls | grep 0000`, however, that returns also the files in which the pattern is located elsewhere in the file and not necessarily 'solo' on a line.

How do you find a pattern using bash that is exclusively present on a single line of the file?

Comment: `ls | grep 0000` doesn't look at file contents at all, it matches file `names` that contain `0000`.

Comment: Hmmm, I think the duplicate might not be correct. Should it match only if there is exactly one line that matches the pattern?

Comment: What's the desired output? The names of the files containing exactly one matching line?

Comment: It should match, if there is at least one line that matches the pattern. Yes, the names are the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have four input files:

```
$ head file*
==> file1 <==
0000
0000

==> file2 <==
abcd
0000
abcd

==> file3 <==
0000x

==> file4 <==
abcd
```

`file4` doesn't contain the pattern at all, `file3` contains the pattern, but it's not on a line on its own, `file1` has multiple lines that contain just the pattern, and `file2` has exactly one line with just the pattern.

To get all files that contain the pattern anywhere:

```
$ grep -l '0000' file*
file1
file2
file3
```

To get all files that contain lines with nothing but the pattern:

```
$ grep -lx '0000' file*
file1
file2
```

And if you wanted only files that contain exactly one line with nothing but the pattern, you could use `-c` to get a count first:

```
$ grep -xc '0000' file*
file1:2
file2:1
file3:0
file4:0
```

and then use awk to print only the files with exactly one match:

```
$ grep -xc '0000' file* | awk -F: '$2==1 {print $1}'
file2
```

With GNU awk, you could also do this directly:

```
$ awk 'BEGINFILE {c=0} /^0000$/ {++c} ENDFILE {if (c==1) print FILENAME}' file*
file2
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to remove the line with the `0000` pattern from the files that contain this pattern? I tried using Awk, however, without succes.

Comment: @user213544 I'm not sure I understand; in general, to remove lines matching a certain pattern, you could use sed: `sed -i '/0000/d' infile` to remove lines containing `0000`, and `sed -i '/^0000$/d' infile` to remove lines containing nothing but `0000`. The `-i` option without a parameter requires GNU sed.